# Why is android-studio TextView invisible?

Tags: android-studio

Why is android-studio TextView invisible after following the Android Studio [Tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/) step by step? The Android Studio version is 3.1.4, `Include Kotlin Support` is checked, and the selected SDK platform API levels are 26, 27, and 28. This is the code for the MainActivity:

```
package com.example.myfirstapp

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
}
```

The `Hello World!` TextView is nowhere to be seen on the Blueprint or Design as can be seen in this screenshot:

[image]

The `Hello World!` is also invisible when running the tutorial app on the emulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set your appTheme to different one, for example Light. It is a button above your preview

Answer (score 0):

Try this in xml

```
android:visibility="visible"
```